# Add tags to blog-posts by php-script

Tags: database, tags

I currently have a different blog software where the blog-post-keywords are in the database record of the blog post. So title, content and keywords are one record, not like in WordPress where each tag is a record in table "wp_terms".

I have now written a PHP script that goes through my blog posts and first checks whether the keyword already exists in the "wp_terms", and if not, enters it there and enters the relationship of the post in the "wp_term_relationships".

In my opinion, the database is fine so far, but in WP the posts still don't have a keyword.

Now the question is, is the linking of the keywords still in other tables, or what else could be the reason? Is anyone familiar with the database structure of WP? Interestingly, "Select from the most used keywords" also says "No keywords found", although wp_terms is full of content...

Comment: Are you using a plugin or custom code to add "keywords" to your site? WordPress Core has Tags, but not Keywords that I'm aware of. It will depend on what plugin or code you're using to enable them.

Comment: directly modifying the WP database only works if you do everything perfectly which usually goes out the window the moment you bring plugins in. Instead everything is much easier if you use the REST API/WP CLI/or do it programmatically with WP APIs, e.g. `wp_insert_post`/`wp_insert_term`/etc

Comment: this is the code I used: https://pastebin.com/xL7qhZ32